# How to connect single-phase appliance to 240v feed?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I had a licensed electrician install this circuit with NEMA 14-30 receptacle before I knew which specific appliance would be used on the circuit.  I now have the appliance with a 14-30 plug, but it warns:

> This  is  a  single-phase  device.  Do  not  connect  all  three
>   phases of a 3-phase feed !!!    You may use any two phases of a three-
>   phase wye-transformer feed.  The center-point of the three phases
>   (usually  used as Neutral) must be grounded somewhere in the system. A
>   Neutral  connection is not required by the LCS.  Only Line 1, Line 2,
>   and Ground  are required.

Is this panel and receptacle properly wired for this single-phase appliance?
[image: Panel][image: Circuit Identified][image: Receptacle][image: Receptacle][image: Receptacle]

Comment: Are you sure that's a 240V appliance? Connecting across 2 phases of a 120V/phase 3-phase supply (as your instruction manual describes) gives you *208V, not 240V*.

Comment: According to the manual (here http://www.clippercreek.com/store/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/LCS-User-Manual-01042016-V3.pdf) it will use a 208v L-L or a 240v L-L since it's probably an entirely switched-mode power converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using the neutral, you should have a NEMA 6-30 receptacle instead of a NEMA 14-30.

Other than that, it looks like you're all set. The black wire is one line (L1), the red wire is another line (L2), and green is ground.  You should have 240 volts between L1 and L2, since you have a 120/240V single split-phase system.

You don't have to worry about the three phase warnings, since you don't have a three phase system.

Comment: Would an L6-30 be acceptable? My plug choices are the 14-30 or L6-30.  I already ordered the 14-30 since that was my receptacle, but I can still change it to L6-30 and rewire the receptacle.

Comment: Since there's not a neutral run to the receptacle, I wouldn't install a 14-30 receptacle. I'd either pull a neutral, or install a 6-30 receptacle. The *L* simply means "*locking*", so it shouldn't be a problem, as long as the device you're plugging in has a L6-30 plug on it.